# Deduction of four-acceleration vector

Tags: special-relativity

Consider an Euclidean metric. The four-accelation vector can be obtained from the time derivative of four-velocity:

$$a^k=\frac{du^k}{d\tau}=\gamma \frac{du^k}{dt}$$

We have that $u^k=(\gamma \vec{u}, ic\gamma)$, where $\vec{u}=(u_x,u_y,u_z)$.

So,

$$a^1=\gamma \frac{ d(\gamma u_x)}{dt}=\gamma\frac{d\gamma}{dt}u_x+ \gamma^2\frac{du_x}{dt}=$$

$$=\frac{\gamma^4}{c^2}u\dot{u}\hspace{2pt}u_x+\gamma^2\dot{u}$$

This result is analogous to $a^2$ and $a^3$ components, and we have for $a^4$:

$$a^4=\gamma ic\frac{d\gamma}{dt}=i\frac{\gamma^4}{c}u\dot{u}$$

We have finally,

$$a^k=\left(\frac{\gamma^4}{c^2}u\dot{u}\vec{u}+\gamma^2\dot{u}, i\frac{\gamma^4}{c}u\dot{u}\right)$$

I've seen in books the following consideration:

$$u\dot{u}=(\vec{u}.\vec{\dot{u}})$$

The problem is that $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{\dot{u}}$ haven't necessarily the same direction. So why is correct to consider the previous equality?

Comment: Also, be careful with the second term in your $a^1$ expression. It is $\dot{u}_x$ and later becomes a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dot{u}$ is not the magnitude of $\dot{\vec{u}}$, it is the derivative of the magnitude $u$.

$$\vec{u}\cdot\vec{u}=u^2$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}\vec{u}\cdot\vec{u}=2\,\vec{u}\cdot\dot{\vec{u}}$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}u^2=2\,u\dot{{u}}$$